# How can I check if a UIButton is being held down?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way with xCode and Swift to check if there is a finger down on a button every so often? I am using SpriteKit and I want to check if a button is being touched in the update method.

Comment: what about the `UIControlEventTouchDown`? was it not good enough for the task?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, set the time to something instant (.1 seconds), and set a flag the a button is being touched. Upon release (there is a delegate method), toggle the flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `button.state == .Highlighted`.

Comment: if (Right.state == UIControlStateHighlighted)

is not working for me, I get a compiler error.

Comment: @ahruss Only if you're in a closure. In Swift you can generally access properties of your own object directly, without self.